# Need to add certain parts of a dictionary in python

Tags: python

Ok, so in our project, we're using a nested dictionary such as:

```
line4 = {'fmlast14': {'quiz1': 100, 'quiz2': 100,
                      'lab1': 100, 'lab2': 100, 'lab3': 100, 'lab4': 100, 'lab5': 75,
                      'exam0': 92}}
```

In the next step, he asks us to "Compute the average quiz, lab, and exam scores. Use the common prefixes of the labels to find the individual quiz, lab, and exam scores. For example, to compute the average lab score for 'fmlast12', sum the scores associated with the five labels that have the prefix 'lab' then divide by five."

I get what he's saying, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to add the elements that only are preceeded by "quiz(x)" or "lab(x)".

Before this part, we were supposed to read the first line and store its labels in a list (we are reading a text file called scores.txt
Then we were supposed to read each subsequent line and store its contents using nested dictionaries. And this is what I got so far:

```
def read_scores(filename):
#with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    #first_line = f.readline()

    f = open(filename)
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines[1:]
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        second_line = f.readline()
        second_line[2:]
    line2 = { 'fmlast12' : {'quiz1' : 66, 'quiz2' : 100, 'lab1' : 100, 'lab2' : 100, 'lab3' : 75, 'lab4' : 75, 'lab5' : 75, 'exam0' : 86}}
    line3 = { 'fmlast13' : {'quiz1' : 100, 'quiz2' : 0, 'lab1' : 100, 'lab2' : 100, 'lab3' : 0, 'lab4' : 50, 'lab5' : 75, 'exam0' : 68}}
    line4 = { 'fmlast14' : {'quiz1' : 100, 'quiz2' : 100, 'lab1' : 100, 'lab2' : 100, 'lab3' : 100, 'lab4' : 100, 'lab5' : 75, 'exam0' : 92}}

def write_report(filename):
    line2 = { 'fmlast12' : {'quiz1' : 66, 'quiz2' : 100, 'lab1' : 100, 'lab2' : 100, 'lab3' : 75, 'lab4' : 75, 'lab5' : 75, 'exam0' : 86}}
    sum(line2.values())


    c = defaultdict(int)
    for d in line2:
        c[d['quiz1']] += d['amt']
```

Answer (score 1):

if this is your standard format of the dictionary , you can try something like

```
# for lab
In [5]: l = [line4['fmlast14'][x] for x in line4['fmlast14'].keys() if x.startswith('lab')]

In [6]: sum(l)/len(l)
Out[6]: 95

# for quiz

In [7]: l2 = [line4['fmlast14'][x] for x in line4['fmlast14'].keys() if x.startswith('quiz')]

In [8]: l2
Out[8]: [100, 100]

In [9]: avg = sum(l2)/len(l2)

In [10]: avg
Out[10]: 100
```

you can also do it like

```
In [22]: [v for k, v in line4['fmlast14'].items() if k.find('quiz') > -1]
Out[22]: [100, 100]

In [23]: [v for k, v in line4['fmlast14'].items() if k.find('lab') > -1]
Out[23]: [100, 100, 100, 100, 75]
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on only your first line where it (eclipse) says that it encountered ":" at line 27 column 11. And expected something else. 

It also says that In is undefined

Comment: it should not give any such error, which python version are you using

Comment: My python interpreter is Python 3.3.
When I try to run it through eclipse, it says that it's invalid syntax.

Comment: Alright, I tried the second snippet, but I still get the same error. Says that "In" is not defined. And that it encountered ":" at line blah blah blah :/

Comment: updated again pls check the last option, and if there is a traceback, paste it

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what you mean by traceback:  File "C:\Users\jhami_000\workspace\cs250_lab6\src\gradereport.py", line 28
    In [23]: [v for k, v in line4['fmlast14'].items() if k.find('lab') > -1]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can also use function to optimize:

```
def getAvg(dVals, keyVal, nameStart):
    vals = [val for key, val in dVals[keyVal].iteritems() if key.startswith(nameStart)]
    return float(sum(vals) / len(vals))

for line in [line2, line3, line4]:
    person = line.keys().pop()
    print "Avg lab for {0} is {1}.".format(person, getAvg(line2, person , 'lab'))
    print "Avg quiz for {0} is {1}.".format(person, getAvg(line2, person , 'quiz'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a good idea to write a function to compute the average

```
>>> line2 = { 'fmlast12' : {'quiz1' : 66, 'quiz2' : 100, 'lab1' : 100, 'lab2' : 100, 'lab3' : 75, 'lab4' : 75, 'lab5' : 75, 'exam0' : 86}}
>>> def get_average(d, prefix):
...     scores = [v for k, v in d.items() if k.startswith(prefix)]
...     return float(sum(scores))/len(scores)
... 
>>> get_average(line2['fmlast12'], 'quiz')
83.0
>>> get_average(line2['fmlast12'], 'lab')
85.0
```

Now you need to sort out your function for reading the scores. It doesn't make much sense at the moment

Comment: what do you mean I need to sort out my functions for reading the scores?

Comment: @user1778404, have you tested it? Why are you opening the file two different ways? Why are you reading the first line into a variable called `second_line`? Why doesn't it return anything?

Comment: No, I have not tested it. And it was stipulated that we had to read the first line in and store the values in a list. Then we had to read from the second line onward. And it doesn't return anything becauseee... I really don't know. Are there any other errors that you see?

Comment: And also, what do I have to return?